# How to use ES6 modules that import modules with relative paths in ClosureScript?

Tags: clojurescript

I am attempting to use Twitter's Bootstrap 4 (beta) in a ClojureScript app. Using the `:npm-deps` compiler option does not work due to [CLJS-2369](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-2369). So my next attempt is to use the `:foreign-libs` compiler option (see [github.com/au-phiware/cljsbuild-bootstrap4](https://github.com/au-phiware/cljsbuild-bootstrap4/tree/foreign-libs)):

```
:foreign-libs [{:file "node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/util.js"
                :provides ["bootstrap.util"]
                :module-type :es6}
               {:file "node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/alert.js"
                :provides ["bootstrap.alert"]
                :requires ["bootstrap.util"]
                :module-type :es6}]})
```

In code, I require the module as:

```
(ns cljsbuild-bootstrap4.core
  (:require [bootstrap.alert :as alert]))
```

But I encounter this error:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Can't resolve './util' in '~/cljsbuild-bootstrap4'
    at onError (~/cljsbuild-bootstrap4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:61:15)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (~/cljsbuild-bootstrap4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (~/cljsbuild-bootstrap4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (~/cljsbuild-bootstrap4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (~/cljsbuild-bootstrap4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (~/cljsbuild-bootstrap4/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
    at innerCallback (~/cljsbuild-bootstrap4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:144:11)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (~/cljsbuild-bootstrap4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (~/cljsbuild-bootstrap4/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:249:35)
    at resolver.doResolve.createInnerCallback (~/cljsbuild-bootstrap4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:44:6)
```

Note: I also tried the following `:foreign-libs` option but received the same result:

```
:foreign-libs [{:file "node_modules/bootstrap/js/src"
                :module-type :es6}]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with 1.9.946. No longer reproducible with 1.10.238.

checked from [CLJS-2369](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-2369)